# Serialization in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization

I'm wondering if in case I need a serialization of some objects in my program, can I simply serialize the constructor parameters and then build a new object with these parameters after deserialization? So I will have two objects from same type and built with the same parameters, can we consider them as perfectly the same objects?

Comment: That's almost two questions. If you make a std::string from "Hello" and some char * which happens to contain "Hello" are they the same string? Also, you can't just save the pointer here - you'd need to save the contants to rebuild the std::string.

Comment: What about state changes to the object after it has been constructed?

Comment: @RichardCritten I got it thanks

Comment: That depends purely on the implementation of your class. If constructing it only involves pure functions which are using the constructor parameters as input, then the constructed class will be deterministically the same. If the constructor does some other things (everything from calling a random generator, doing IO, calling libraries which do one of these, etc.) then the outcome might be different.